# Pass php array to Ajax variable

Tags: javascript, php

i need to pass an array variable to Ajax request

```
<?
   $postData = array(
   'FirstName'=>$_POST['user_name'],
   'Telephone'=>$_POST['user_phone'],
   'Description' =>$_POST['komment'],   
   'Classifierid'=>'5E0696FD-831E-E611-9426-005056BAB261'
);

$postData = json_encode($postData);?>
```

i need to pass $postData to ajax variable data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var postData=<?php $postData ?>;
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://XXXXXXXXX/api/CallBackForm",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: I need to put $posData here,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    });
```

`

I get the $postData successfully. All the code is in one php page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `$postData` like :

```
<?php $postData = json_encode(array('FirstName'=>$_POST['user_name'])); ?>
```

You can send directly the Json without `datatype` like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://XXXXXXXXX/api/CallBackForm",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '<?php echo $postData; ?>',
});
```

Or if you have to use the `dataType: 'json'` and ContentType option (important for server side), you can parse the json before sending ajax like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://XXXXXXXXX/api/CallBackForm",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.parse('<?php echo $postData; ?>'),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think you have to JSON.parse a JSON string when you use it in JavaScript as a variable? Like so: `var postData = <?php echo $postData; ?>;`

Comment: Without parse the json, i think Ajax will send a serialisation of the serialised array like : `"string": "\" { \"toto\" }\""`